# Is there a way to get the Reeking Cave Unusual Gem before the associated main quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to get Prowler's Profit early in the game and I've been ignoring the main quest-line. In fact, I'm still on the quest after Unbound. I'm running the latest patches (and unofficial ones), so the [Unusual Gem must be in the Reeking Cave](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Reeking_Cave#Notes). It seems the Reeking Cave can only be accessed (without Whirlwind Sprint) through the Thalmor Embassy, but the compound is walled off and the front gate is locked and can't be picked. There doesn't appear to be anyone outside of the walls, and I've read that nobody has the key anyway. I've tried coaxing some guards to come at me, but they won't open the gate.

Is it possible to get this Unusual Gem without Diplomatic Immunity? If so, how?

Update: I did find a way in, but I warn that it may be futile. I acquired the quest by reading the book in the chest, which is the only way to spawn the guards that are supposed to hold keys to the Reeking Cave door (because the other trigger doesn't spawn), but neither of the guards were holding keys to it. What a wild goose chase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, easily. Enter the cave from the back-end, at the end of the road at the base of the mountain-atop-which-lays-the-Thalmor-Embassy.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4BDu.jpg

Answer (score -1):

The stone is near a dead conjurer, befor you enter the path out, in the trolls lair. The troll wont usually be in the lair, but if you wait a few minutes, he will go back to it. The stone is next the conjurers hand.

Comment: This answer, in itself, does not answer the asked question. Perhaps you meant to post this as a comment?